# Passing additional parameters in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of hotels and I am passing a URL friendly slug for the hotel in the parameter in the URL hotel/nice-hotel.

This is ok and fine.

I want to also pass the hotel ID to the next page but don't want pass it in the URL. What is the best way of doing this?

```
       .state('hotels', { 
            title: 'Hotels page',
            url: '/hotels',
            controller: 'HotelsController',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/hotels/hotelsView.html'
        })

        .state('hotel', { 
            title: 'Hotel page',
            url: '/hotel/:hotelName',
            controller: 'HotelController',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/hotel/hotelView.html'
            params:{hotelId:hotelId};
        })
```

The link I'm passing

```
<a type="button" ui-sref="hotel({hotelId:{{hotel.hotelId}},hotelName:{hotel.hotelName}})" href="/hotel/{{hotel.name | slugify}}" class="ach-hl-btn btn btn-warning">Select</a>
```

Comment: are you using ui-router?

Comment: yes i'm using ui-router

Comment: @ottz0: well, show your route for the "next page" then

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `ui-router`, you can use `params`:

```
.state('stateName', {
    //other config
    params: {
        id: id_value
    }
})
```

And you can access the value in your controller using `$stateParams`:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams);
}]
```

Comment: how do I use it in the link. href="/hotel/{{hotel.name | slugify}}

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('stateName', {
//other config
controller:stateNameControler,
params: {
    id: id_value
}})
```

this may raise some errors if you son't accept the stateParams in the controller of that state

```
app.controller('stateNameControler', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
console.log($stateParams);}]
```

If you don't want your params at the link,you can use **params** in the sateprovider like this

```
.state('playgame',{
            url: "/play",
            params:{ src     :null,
                     gameName:null} ,
            templateUrl: "partials/play.html",
            controller:'gamePlayController'
          })
```

Now on your corresponding controller

```
mainApp.controller('gamePlayController', ['$scope','$state','$http','Game','Facebook','$stateParams', function($scope,$state,$http,$Game,Facebook,$stateParams){
      var imageElement=document.getElementById("image");
      imageElement.src=$stateParams.src;
      // $scope.dagi=$stateParams.data;
      console.log($stateParams.gameName);
      $scope.goBack=function(){
        $state.go($stateParams.gameName);
      }


    }]);
```

In your mark up

```
<button ng-click="onClick()"></button>
```

and your function `

```
$scope.onClick(){$state.go('stateName',{'src':dataURL,'gameName':$scope.gameName}); }
```

Comment: How do I use it in the link?

Comment: How do you use the link though? <a type="button" ui-sref="hotel({hotelId:{{hotel.hotelId}},hotelName:{hotel.hotelName}})" href="/hotel/{{hotel.name | slugify}}" class="ach-hl-btn btn btn-warning">Select</a>

Comment: oh okay you can call a function on button click and do this , inject $state, in the controller $state.go("stateName",{param:value,param:value})  I will update the answer for you

Comment: dont forget to inject $state

Comment: How does it go for you?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the hotel name was being passed in the URL, it is not needed in the params. It can still be accessed in the subsequent page using $stateParams

Using ui-router

```
       .state('hotels', { 
            title: 'Hotels page',
            url: '/hotels',
            controller: 'HotelsController',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/hotels/hotelsView.html
        })

        .state('hotel', { 
            title: 'Hotel page',
            url: '/hotel/:hotelName',
            controller: 'HotelController',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/hotel/hotelView.html',
            params:{
                hotelId:{key:'value'},
            }
        })
```

The link was passed using ui-sref

```
<a type="button" ui-sref="hotel({hotelId:hotel.hotelId, hotelName:hotel.name})" >Select</a>
```

This can be accessed in the controller of the hotel pages by using $stateParams

```
console.log($stateParams);
```